# Scroll parallax effect with a background position set in percentage

Tags: javascript

I'm learning how to create a scroll parallax effect following this [guide](https://www.devstreak.com/parallax-scrolling-effect-with-pure-javascript/). So far so good, but then I realize that my background position is set to '50%'(center). So when I run my js, the background position unit is changed from **%** to **px** hence it position is not what I expected.

How can I write the code so the background position change in percentage?

Here is the code:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
  var bgParallax = document.getElementsByClassName('parallax')[0];
  var limit = bgParallax.offsetTop + bgParallax.offsetHeight;  
  if (scrollPosition > bgParallax.offsetTop && scrollPosition <= limit){
    bgParallax.style.backgroundPositionY = scrollPosition / 2 + 'px';   
  }else{
    bgParallax.style.backgroundPositionY = '0';    
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  height:600px;
}
.parallax{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
  background-image:url('http://68.media.tumblr.com/9c811fb09ae9fe61e3bbcb1d7f0c3724/tumblr_o9489fIsmH1qhttpto3_1280.png');
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='parallax'></div>
```

And here is a **[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/GhostOrder/pen/zwWaRj)**

PPD: I can't change my html or css and I need solve this with pure javascript for learning purposes.

Comment: Have you considered just using a library for this (they are fairly common) instead of re-inventing the wheel (also common, but not usually recommended)?

Comment: That would be an fast fix, and I'm not against fast fixes but since I learning javascript I think is important to fix all I can with just pure javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

It's essentially the same thing, just starting at 50% instead of 0px, and subtracting as you scroll down, depending on how far the image should move. (10% in this case, so `backgroundPositionY` varies from 40% to 50%)

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
  var bgParallax = document.getElementsByClassName('parallax')[0];
  var limit = bgParallax.offsetTop + bgParallax.offsetHeight;  
  if (scrollPosition > bgParallax.offsetTop && scrollPosition <= limit){
    bgParallax.style.backgroundPositionY = (50 - 10*scrollPosition/limit) + '%';   
  }else{
    bgParallax.style.backgroundPositionY = '50%';    
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  height:600px;
}
.parallax{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
  background-image:url('http://68.media.tumblr.com/9c811fb09ae9fe61e3bbcb1d7f0c3724/tumblr_o9489fIsmH1qhttpto3_1280.png');
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='parallax'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly I was looking for.